# pip3 install を実行すると TLS/SSL 利用不可でエラーとなる

Tags: python, ssl, pycharm

PyCharm上のターミナルで pip3 install を実行したのですがエラーになります。解決方法が分からず困っています。何か心当たりのある方、ご意見いただけないでしょうか？

ちなみにアプリケーションから直接ターミナルを起動した場合は、pip3 install が成功するので、環境変数か権限の問題のような気はしています。

### ▼実行環境

- macOS Catalina ver10.15.3
- PyCharm 2020.04.07
- pip3(pip) ver 20.1 (python 3.7)
- Xcode 11.4.1 (https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ からDLしインストール)
- python環境：brew + 仮想環境
- 自宅PC (proxy利用の無)
- ~/.bash_profile内の定義（export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"）

### ▼試したこと

- pip3 の再インストール
- opensslの再インストール（brew install openssl）

### ▼その他

- ①PyCharm上のターミナル上で pip3 -V を実行した時と、
  ②アプリケーションから直接ターミナルを起動し pip3 -V を実行した時で
  実行結果が異なります。

  ①の実行結果：pip 20.1 from /Users/[ディレクトリ名]/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
  ②の実行結果：pip 20.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
- mac ターミナル（アプリケーションから起動）上での実行結果
  $ brew list
  autoconf        pkg-config      readline
  gdbm            pyenv           sqlite
  openssl         pyenv-virtualenv    xz
  openssl@1.1     python
- PyCharm ターミナル上での実行結果
  $ brew list
  autoconf                openssl                 pkg-config              
  pyenv-virtualenv        readline                xz
  gdbm                    openssl@1.1             pyenv                   
  python                  sqlite

### ▼エラー内容

```
(venv) $ pip3 install Flask==1.0.2
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==1.0.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask==1.0.2
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: もしかしたらこれらの記事が参考になるかも。[Macでpip install -U pipがSSLエラーになる](https://engineer.kasajei.com/entry/2018/07/28/pip_upgrade), [pip3 install したらSSLエラーになった（MacOS環境)](https://qiita.com/odashun1015/items/5ac555551f82c49d2efc)

Comment: mac利用ということで環境をもう少し詳しく教えていただけないですか。 example: ・xcodeの有無 +　ver.
・python環境について [ mac純正 or brew ] + 仮想環境かどうか
・pip ver.
・開発環境 会社なのか自宅pcなのか(proxy利用の有無)　／　こちらの情報の方が原因追及をし易いので助かります。
また、Pycharmを使わなければならない状況ではなければ別の方法もあります。 ご参考までに。

Comment: ありがとうございます！環境情報を追加しました。PyCharmを使いたい理由は、今、学習サイト（Udemy）でPythonを使ったプログラム実装の演習をしており、その演習でPyCharmが使用されているからです。必須という訳ではないのですが、できれば演習と同じ環境で演習を進めたいのです。